# Update String PK DotNet Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model like:

```
[Required]
public string Mfowcode { get; set; } = null!;
public string Mfowdesc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Then I have the following command like:

```
public async Task<BaseResponse> Handle(UpdateOwnershipCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = new BaseResponse();
    try
    {
        var entity = await _context.Mfows.FindAsync(new object?[] { request.OwnershipCode }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken) ?? throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Mfow), request.OwnershipCode);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.OwnershipCode))
        {
            entity.MfowCode = request.OwnershipCode;
            entity.MfowDescription = request.OwnershipDescription;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            response.SetReturnSuccessStatus();
            response.Data = entity;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.SetReturnStatus(DanaPensiunConstants.ERROR_STATUS, ex.Message);
        response.Data = null;
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return response;
}
```

When I tried to update the `Mfowcode`, error appears like `Mfowcode` not found. When I tried to debug. It stops at this line:

`var entity = await _context.Mfows.FindAsync(new object?[] { request.OwnershipCode }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken) ?? throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Mfow), request.OwnershipCode);`

I know that it because the `Request.OwnershipCode` has been changed when user submit the form.

Is there a way to change the code to resolve this issue?
Need advice please.

Thank you.

Comment: I am confused about your code, Is `Mfowcode` the primary key in your mode? Why you do query first then check if `request.OwnershipCode`  is null. could you explain your code?

Comment: @XinranShen, yes. Mfowcode is the primary key. `request.OwnershipCode` is the field on the page which means is the value of `Mfowcode`.

Comment: OK, But I am still confused why you use `entity.MfowCode = request.OwnershipCode;` to update primary key?

Comment: Let say, the `Mfowcode` is `"GRP-XYZ"`. This code has been used by another table. The user just know that the code is typo. It should be `"GRP-XYZZ"`. If I create a new record for this new code, then user need to update all related table. The idea is, user just need to update the code on that table.